# Why is HTML not taking the values of a,b,c in my below code snippet?

Tags: html, css

I've started learning html/css. I have been trying to create a block on my webpage where adjusting the sliders pertaining to the red, green and blue colors will change the display block color according to the rgb values adjusted by the user but it seems I am doing some mistake as the intended display block is not reflecting any color at all!

Here is my code snippet.

```
<div>
    <form action="/actionPage.html" oninput="a.value=parseInt(a.value);b.value=parseInt(b.value);c.value=parseInt(c.value);">
        0
        <input type="range" id="a" name="a" />
        255
        <br />
        0
        <input type="range" id="b" name="b" />
        255
        <br />
        0
        <input type="range" id="c" name="c" />
        255
        <br />
        <div style="background-color: rgb(a,b,c); height: 50px; width: 200px; border: thin solid black;">                    
        </div>                            
    </form>       
</div>
```

Currently, the box below my 3 color-sliders does not show any color at all. I want that box to show the rgb color obtained from the combination of rgb inputs given by the user by selecting slider positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't work like that, automatically listening to if a variable is updating. Once the variables has hit the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), it's stale and can't change. If you inspect the div element, you will see that the background-color isn't valid.

Instead, the form needs to call a function that finds the element you want to update, and then update the element with code.

I had to add an `id` to your div in order to find it. I also added `max` to all your input ranges.

```js
function updateColorDiv(r, g, b) {      
  let colorDiv = document.getElementById('color');
  let backgroundColor = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
  
  colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
  colorDiv.innerText = backgroundColor;
}
```

```css
#color {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: thin solid black; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form action="/actionPage.html" oninput="updateColorDiv(parseInt(a.value), parseInt(b.value), parseInt(c.value))">
        0
        <input type="range" id="a" name="a" min="0" max="255"/>
        255
        <br />
        0
        <input type="range" id="b" name="b" min="0" max="255" />
        255
        <br />
        0
        <input type="range" id="c" name="c" min="0" max="255" />
        255

        <div id="color" />
    </form>       
</div>
```